# Why I can't see my navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have read similar threads about this issue in StackOverflow but none of them solved my problem. Usually, I have no issue setting up the Navigation Controller. As you can see in the picture below, I have set my View Controller embedded in the Navigation Controller:

(Authentication Storyboard)
[image]

But when I run the project, I can't see my Navigation Bar, like in the picture below:

[image]

I am presenting my VC using show segue:

[image]

I don't know if this gives effect or not but the first picture above is actually my Authentication Storyboard. I try to separate the authentication process in the "Authentication Storyboard". The main storyboard will be like this:

[image]

I have also set the navigation bar visibility to enable. What went wrong in here?

[image]

Comment: How are you presenting your V.C.?  Is your segue a push, or are you presenting modally?

Comment: I use push show segue

Comment: How are you triggering your segue? via storyboard segue? via navigation controller?

Comment: via storyboard segue

Comment: Can you share your project, say, on Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here seems to be the setup of your storyboard connections between your Tab Bar, Navigation and View Controllers.

This can be done in many different ways, but a fast way to do it is selecting your `Main AuthVC` and clicking on the menu: `Editor -> Embed in -> Tab Bar Controller`). Then, repeat the process but embedding it to a Navigation Controller (`Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller`. And lastly, set the Tab Bar Controller as the Initial View Controller.

It should look something like this: 
[image]

This would solve the problem with the Navigation Bar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After Tab bar Controller add Navigation view controller.Then add your view controller.[image]